# Use NMAKE to make all source in a directory?

Tags: c++, makefile, visual-c++, nmake

Using nmake, is it possible to have the makefile build all the .cpp files in the current directory automatically, without having to specify them individually?

So, instead of something like:

```
O = $(OBJ_DIR)/main.obj
{$(SOURCE_DIR)}.cpp{$(OBJ_DIR)}.obj:
    ---COMPILE $< HERE---
```

I'd like to avoid having to specify each obj to make.  Can this be done?

Comment: I think this can be done with wild cards in GNU make (and IIRC you can run it on windows). Aside from that, I'm sorry but I don't known `nmake`.

Answer (score 3):

Just

```
main.exe: *.c resource.RES
    @$(MAKE) $(**:.c=.obj)
    link $(**:.c=.obj) /OUT:$@
```

and you don't need to add anything else! Every time you `nmake`, all `*.c` will be checked if it is compiled or not.

Details:

- `$**` for the dependencies
- `$@` for the target
- `$(**:.c=.obj)` is a string substitute, replacing the `.c` suffix with `.obj`. And when it comes to `resource.RES`, it will not replace anything.

Note that there is a recursive call, and this is the most elegant approach. Otherwise it is necessary to get all `*.c` filenames with manners like a script.

Comment: Thank you, this should probably be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a rule like this:

```
{src\mystuff}.c{tmp\src\mystuff}.obj::
    $(CC) /nologo $(CFLAGS) /c /Fotmp\src\mystuff\ $<
```

which will find and compile all the `.c` files in `src\mystuff` and put the object files in `tmp\src\mystuff`.  Substitute `.cpp` for `.c` in your case.

Note that the first character on the second line should be a tab, not spaces.

Also, `$(CC)` is predefined by nmake to be `cl`, and you can add any compiler flags you need to `$(CFLAGS)`, hard-code them in the rule or add a different variable there, as you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

```
.cpp.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $*.cpp
```

is a default rule that will automatically resolve .obj dependencies from .cpp files...

Comment: Well, no.  It just explains how to do it, it doesn't cause it to be done.

Comment: @reinierpost yes you are technically correct.  That is true of the entire makefile; it describes the actions required to resolve dependencies, and produce outputs.

Comment: Well, I think you answer a different question than the one anon means to ask, but as others are providing the same answer, I guess I'm wrong.

Comment: @reinierpost, you could be right - he hasn't accepted any answer, and his question is worded such that the answers given might not address his question.  I don't see an answer from you? Maybe you should take a stab at it?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to wrap the make in a script.

Either use a for loop, calling make on each .cpp file or construct a list of cpp files and use it as a parameter to the makefile.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a shell command during nmakefile preprocessing, and then `!include` the output. Naturally the output needs to be in nmake format. Something like:

```
!if [bash -c "echo O = *.cpp" >sources.mak]
!error Failed to generate source list
!endif
!include sources.mak

all: $(O:.cpp=.obj)

.cpp.obj:
    ---COMPILE $< HERE---
```

I suspect that most people would not use *bash* to create `sources.mak`, but you get the idea.