# wildcard not recognised when migrating makefile to windows

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to modify a makefile in a way s.th. it can be run with `nmake` on Windows (7, in my case) and change from gcc to icl.

As I don't know much about creating makefiles OR compiling C code on windows, I'm having some trouble in getting this to work ...

The original makefile looked like this:

```
# ==================================================================================== #
# = Executable
# ==================================================================================== #

BIN = rename_me

# ==================================================================================== #
# = Compiler settings
# ==================================================================================== #

CC      = gcc
CFLAGS += -O3 -std=c99 -Wall
LIBS   +=

# ==================================================================================== #
# = Object Files
# ==================================================================================== #

%.o : %.c %.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%.s : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -S $< -o $@

SRCS=$(wildcard *.c)

OBJS=$(SRCS:.c=.o)

all: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) -o $(BIN)

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
    rm -rf $(BIN)
```

First, `+=` doesn't exist for nmake.

Neither does `-o` for the windows icl compiler.

So what I did, was

```
# ==================================================================================== #
# = Executable
# ==================================================================================== #

BIN = rename_me.exe

# ==================================================================================== #
# = Compiler settings
# ==================================================================================== #
CC      = icl
# += is an extension not supported by windows
CFLAGS = /O3 /C99 /Wall $(CFLAGS)
LIBS   = $(LIBS)

# ==================================================================================== #
# = Object Files
# ==================================================================================== #
# no -o on win
%.o : %.c %.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) /c $<

%.s : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) /S $<

SRCS=$(wildcard *.c)

OBJS=$(SRCS:.c=.o)

all: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

clean:
    del /S/F *.o
    del /S/F $(BIN)
```

Yeah, crude, but I thought I should see if it runs before I try to find a more elegant solution for `BIN`

Well, it doesn't.

> makefile(53) : fatal error U1000: Syntax error: missing ")"

Line 53, that's `SRCS=$(wildcard *.c)`.

I don't see anything wrong with that line, though.

Answer (score 1):

`wildcard` is a GNU make extension. The error message you posted looks like one from `nmake` which doesn't support this feature.

Use GNU Make (e.g. through MinGW) instead (or rewrite the Makefile if that's feasible).

Comment: How would the makefile have to be rewritten?

Comment: Explicitly listing the source files would be the easiest route. If you have to generate it at build time, check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841597/use-nmake-to-make-all-source-in-a-directory). But you are already using `gcc`, so `gmake` is probably available too. Just use that.

Comment: I'm not using gcc ... I think I did mention my changing from gcc to icl exactly because I don't want to use MinGW.

Comment: Oh, I mistook the first Makefile as being your current one. Didn't any of the suggestions in the question I linked work out of you?